# How can I check checkbox which is exists in model sepereted by coma from database (as shown below in code) using MVC asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Below is code of javascript. I want my checkboxes are selected based on coma seperated values from database. please let me know where i am mistaken

```js
function GetStatesList() {
  debugger;
  var makeList = [];
  var url = '/IAAISettings/GetStatesList';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(stateList) {
      var makeChkList = ""
      for (var i = 0; i < stateList.length; i++) {
        var st = stateList[i];
        makeChkList += "<div class=\"col-12\">" +
          "<label class=\"checkbox\">" +
          "<input type=\"checkbox\"  id=\"State_" + stateList[i] + "\" name=\"State_" + stateList[i] + "\" checked=\"" + @Model.States.Contains("Alaska") ? "checked" + "\" value=\"" + stateList[i] + "\">" +
          "<i></i>" + stateList[i] +
          "</label>" +
          "</div>";
      }
      document.getElementById('StateschkList').innerHTML = makeChkList;
    },
    error: function(r) {
      OnFailure(r);
    },
    failure: function(r) {
      OnFailure(r);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found issue. because of js is client side and model loads before js load it was not getting modal value and to get value we have to use this line
**@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.States));**

```js
function GetStatesList() {
        debugger;
        var arrstates = [];
        var url = '/IAAISettings/GetStatesList';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            success: function (stateList) {
                var makeChkList = ""
                var st =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.States));
                arrstates = st.split(",");
                console.log(st);
                for (var i = 0; i < stateList.length; i++) {
                    var str = stateList[i];
                    
                    if (arrstates.includes(stateList[i])) {
                        makeChkList += "<div class=\"col-12\">" +
                            "<label class=\"checkbox\">" +
                            "<input type=\"checkbox\"  id=\"State_" + stateList[i] + "\" name=\"State_" + stateList[i] + "\" checked=checked\"" + "\" value=\"" + stateList[i] + "\">" +
                            "<i></i>" + stateList[i] +
                            "</label>" +
                            "</div>";
                    }
                    else {
                        makeChkList += "<div class=\"col-12\">" +
                            "<label class=\"checkbox\">" +
                            "<input type=\"checkbox\"  id=\"State_" + i + "\" name=\"State_" + i + "\" value=\"" + stateList[i] + "\">" +
                            "<i></i>" + stateList[i] +
                            "</label>" +
                            "</div>";
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('StateschkList').innerHTML = makeChkList;
            },
            error: function (r) {
                OnFailure(r);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                OnFailure(r);
            }
        });
    }
```